# Uncaught reference error: Function not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some simple code for one of my first jquery scripts, I'm trying to call it's function but it keeps saying the function doesn't exist! I have check the spelling and I'm sure I had this working before but I have no idea what's changed.

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/6LLpC/

This is how I'm calling my function:

```
jQuery(function($){
applyField();
});
```

Can anyone show me where I went wrong please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`applyField` isn't defined because jsFiddle wraps your code in an `onload` event handler. So the function is only visible in this event handler.

Choose `"no wrap - in <head>"` in the left menu :

[image]

Alternatively, you could also call your function from this event handler, this would be more coherent.

Note that calling the function isn't enough. If you want your event binding to be effective, change

```
$(this).on('change', '#apply',function() {
```

to

```
$(document.body).on('change', '#apply',function() {
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/LKJRP/)

Comment: That still doesn't work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/6LLpC/2/

Comment: or keep the function itself inside the `jQuery(function()` wrap.. Something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/6LLpC/4/).

Comment: @Jimmy It works for me : http://jsfiddle.net/LKJRP/

Comment: Ok it works but hides all my other fields: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/LKJRP/1/

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on but in chrome it is hiding other fields!? http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/LKJRP/6/embedded/result/

Comment: @Jimmy As far as I know, it does what you seem to want. What do you want different ?

Comment: In my updated example I've added in additional input fields such as <input type="file" name="company logo" placeholder="Add company logo"> which aren't being shown, but when I remove the javascript they do show.

Comment: @Jimmy : Check my updates

Comment: @Jimmy If the problem is that you're hiding too many inputs, give the hidable ones some class and replace $('input') with $('.hidable').

Answer (score 1):

After fixing the `onload` issue, your second problem is `this` is not a parent of the `<select>` element, in your function. In order to use that style of `.on` you need to pass in a parent of the element you're targeting (which can be document).

Change from:

```
$(this).on('change', '#apply',function() {
```

To:

```
$(document).on('change', '#apply',function() {
```

Also, to prevent hiding all inputs, I suggest using a class instead of selecting `$('input')`. See fiddle.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6LLpC/11/)

Comment: Am I literally going insane?! Why do these examples all stop other inputs from displaying - see here: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/6LLpC/9/

Comment: @Jimmy see my updated fiddle for a fix. It's because you hide all inputs, instead you can use a class to differentiate them.

Answer (score 1):

### **[Approach - 1 => Click here for Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6LLpC/12/)**

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
applyField();
});

// Apply Fields
function applyField() {
    $(this).on('change', '#apply',function() {
        var selected = $(this).find(':selected').val(),
            elem = $("#"+selected);
        $("input").addClass('hidden');
        elem.removeClass('hidden');
        $(".donthide").show();
    });
    $("#apply").trigger('change');
};
```

### **[Approach - 2=> Click here for Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MJGmg/13/)**

**JQuery**

`on` needed to execute the function after the DOM is ready.. Check demo.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(this).on('change', '#apply',function() {
        var selected = $(this).find(':selected').val(),
            elem = $("#"+selected);
        $("input").addClass('hidden');
        elem.removeClass('hidden');
        $(".donthide").show();
    });
    $("#apply").trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: Can you explain what you've changed and how it solves the problem?

Comment: Your example also hides other fields, I can't see the file upload one for example in chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/6LLpC/8/

Comment: @Jimmy : Please check updates